# Date is reducing by 1 day when storing into postgresql database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In my node app i am using postgresql as my DB. In that i have a field name `startdate`.  Its working fine in my local system. When i hosted my app in digital ocean the date is reducing by 1 day and storing into the DB...

My model:

```
"properties": {
    "startDate": {
      "type": "date",      
      "required": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "startdate",
        "dataType": "date",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": null,
        "dataScale": null,
        "nullable": "YES"
      }
    }
```

Suppose consider i am updating the date as `"startDate":"2016-02-11".But its storing as`2016-02-10`. Its very strange to me. Please share your ideas on this. Thanks in advance..

EDIT:
My DigitalOcean current date is as follows:

```
Thu Jun 16 05:36:48 EDT 2016
```

and my local date is as follows:

```
Thu Jun 16 15:07:17 IST 2016
```

EDT and IST will make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timezone difference that you mentioned is absolutely correct as IST is +0530 UTC and EDT is -0400 UTC, so there is a time difference of 0930 hours. Now what you can do is change timezone of postgre server to UTC and save the date in UTC or change the timezone of Digital Ocean server to UTC so that only UTC date is saved in the DB.

Comment: run 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' and select timezone as UTC so that your server code in node.js process the timezone as UTC.

Comment: That you must check. If, in your code you are not doing any time conversions or using new Date() then its ok. If your project is in a mature stage then I advice you to check if there is some code which is converting between time zones and correct it. You can also accept the answer if you liked it. :P

Comment: new Date() won't impact the new data but it might impact the previous data in your DB as that is not UTC.

Comment: Just select none of the above and it will show you the option for UTC.

Comment: Try to change the timezone of Postgre server.

Comment: You can set 'timezone' param into 'pgsql/data/postgresql.conf'.

Comment: i set the time zone of postgres using SET TIME ZONE asia/kolkata, but its still not working..

Comment: Wheteher i have to restart the DB once i modified??

Comment: Yes. Restart the DB server.